# How to pass a Cray pointer into subroutine?

Tags: fortran, fortran77, cray-pointers

I pass a Cray pointer which be mapped with a variable into a Fortran subroutine. It is described as below:

```
program test
  integer val
  pointer (ptr_val, val)

  print *, "1:", loc(val)
  print *, "1:", ptr_val

  CALL DPMALLOC(ptr_val, sizeof(val))

  print *, "2:", loc(val)
  print *, "2:", ptr_val

  val = 999
  call foo(val)

end program test

subroutine foo(val)
  integer val
  print *, "3:",val
  print *, "3:", loc(val)
  print *, "3:", ptr_val
  call DPMALLOC(ptr_val, sizeof(val))
  print *, "4:", ptr_val
  print *, "4:", loc(val)
  return
end subroutine foo
```

```
void dpmalloc_(void **data, int *size){ 
    *data =(void *) malloc(*size);
    printf("malloc\n");
}
```

Output:

```
 1:                   0
 1                    0
 2:             30743328
 2:             30743328
 3:         999
 3:             30743328
 3:  7.82827652E-38
 4:  7.82833033E-38
 4:             30743328
```

Therefore, it seems I cannot use a global pointer in subroutine. How can I fix it?

Comment: Actually you are not using Fortran 77. Cray pointers were never a part of that or any other international standard, and thus are inherently non-portable. As such there is no well defined way to do this; you will have to read your compiler documentation.

Comment: What compiler you use may be important. And sometimes it makes sense to bit the bullet and move towards fortran90... e.g. replacing c_malloc with ALLOCATE, etc.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/293353

Comment: To make your question answerable you should tell us more. I am missing the code, or at least headers, of the subroutines. And I am also missing the description of your actual problem. What is your question? Is there arny error message? How does it look like? Or a wrong result? A crash?

Comment: But note that using both `val` and `ptr_val` sounds very suspicious to me. If you change `ptr_val` I expect a crash or a similar disaster.

Comment: If you add `implicit none` to the subroutine (and main program), you'll notice that you haven't a "global pointer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  francescalus points you really should be always using `IMPLICIT NONE`. It is very very important. If you must don't have to care about strict FORTRAN77 compatibility, because Cray pointers are an extension anyway. So do use `IMPLICIT NONE`!

That will tell you that `ptr_val` was undefined in the subroutine.

Instead you should pass the pointer, not the array, and declare the pointer association again in the subroutine:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer val
  pointer (ptr_val, val)

  print *, "1:", loc(val)
  print *, "1:", ptr_val

  CALL DPMALLOC(ptr_val, sizeof(val))



  print *, "2:", loc(val)
  print *, "2:", ptr_val

  val = 999
  call foo(ptr_val)

end program test

subroutine foo(ptr_val)
  implicit none

  integer val
  pointer (ptr_val, val)

  print *, "3:",val
  print *, "3:", loc(val)
  print *, "3:", ptr_val
  call DPMALLOC(ptr_val, sizeof(val))
  print *, "4:", ptr_val
  print *, "4:", loc(val)
  return
end subroutine foo
```

output:

```
> ./a.out 
 1:                    0
 1:                    0
malloc
 2:             10391632
 2:             10391632
 3:         999
 3:             10391632
 3:             10391632
malloc
 4:             10391392
 4:             10391392
```